# Unique task queue task names only for active duration

Tags: java, google-app-engine, queue

I want to guarantee that a task is not in a task queue more then once, so I generate a unique name based on it's payload. But, that task name is [reserved for up to 7 days](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview.html#Worker_URLs_and_Task_Names), which is not what I want; I only want it reserved for the duration the task is queued; it could be immediately re-queued.

> Once a Task with name N is written,
>   any subsequent attempts to insert a
>   Task named N will fail. Eventually (at
>   least seven days after the task
>   successfully executes), the task will
>   be deleted and the name N can be
>   reused.

Is there a way to check if the named task is already in the queue then add it if it's not? Or a totally different approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take a different approach - for example, including the time interval over which you want the name to be unique in the task name, or including a 'job number' that you increment for each new task.

Comment: Nick has an example of computing a task name which includes the time interval [here](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/05/App-Engine-Cookbook-On-demand-Cron-Jobs) (though in Python the concept will be straightforward to implement in Java as well).

Comment: I get the solution as it applies to my situation, but I don't see how using tasks for updates at periodic intervals is different from using a cron job.

Comment: I'm jealous that in python you're allowed to use dashes in task names.

Comment: @antony Because you get to schedule the jobs at runtime, rather than having to pre-specify it in a configuration file at design time. There's also no need to schedule jobs for intervals that you know will have no work that requires doing.

Comment: gotchu. you should include the link to the post in your answer. thanks again.